# form submit issues when protocol is http

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, https

We have recently switched to `HTTPS` and when submitting login form it goes to error page.

I see that I use the URL as `http://` instead of `https://`. But I want my form to submit even it I use the plain `http://` URL.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: what error code is being returned?

Comment: No error in screen. When I check using Inspect it shows " Message: Call to undefined function base_url()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "application/config/autoload.php."

add..

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or you can add in controller also..

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Or instead of helper settings.. you can add following code to .htaccess bottom..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: provide more details by editing your question just like config url declaration, htaccess code, autoload helpers declarations sections

Answer (score 0):

Change .Htaccess File

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourDomainName\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yourDomainName.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ yourDomainName.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set dynamic base url to solve this issue. In your config/config.php, try this:

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```